# array_keys returns in addition to correct results wrong results

Tags: php, arrays

(question edited)
I been struggeling with this script for while and cant get it to work right.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'description'     => 'Permanent modification of a ship\'s shield facilities.',
        'hasTypes'        => 'false',
        'iconID'          => 2703,
        'marketGroupID'   => 954,
        'marketGroupName' => 'Shield Rigs',
        'parentGroupID'   => 943
    ),
    1 => array('description'     =>
        'Equipment modules for spaceships, including many types of weapon, electronic, engineering, armor, shield and propulsion systems',
        'hasTypes'        => 'false',
        'iconID'          => 1432,
        'marketGroupID'   => 9,
        'marketGroupName' => 'Ship Equipment',
        'parentGroupID'   => 'TesT'
    )
);

$keys = array_keys(array_column($array, 'parentGroupID'), 'TesT',true);

var_dump($keys);
```

this works but complete script returns keys with parentGroupID value different than TesT.

[complete script with full array](https://paste.ee/p/ulxie)

adding following to complete script shows that the parentgroupid is not equal to TesT on all keys returned by array_keys.

```
$response = array();
foreach($keys as $key){
$response[$key] = $array[$key]['parentGroupID'];


}

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: What is the output and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: It returns exactly as it should, a match. https://3v4l.org/ti0oZ

Comment: d3vi0ussander, you need to edit your question and add information on what you expect to see as @JensV suggested.  Saying things like 'false positives' and 'full array' is too abstract; people need to know in detail what you are trying to achieve in order to help :)

Comment: after a while i was able to add whole script that will reveal the problem.

Comment: Your "complete script with full array" works as expected. `$col = array_column($array, 'parentGroupID');
foreach ($keys as $k)
  echo $col[$k], PHP_EOL;` All values are `"TesT"`

Comment: Quasimodo hmm u are right it does show it like that but adding  this to end of script.   $response = array();
foreach($keys as $key){
$response[$key] = $array[$key]['parentGroupID'];


}

var_dump($response); //tells other story.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
$op = array();
foreach($ar as $value){
if($value['parentGroupID'] === 'TesT'){
array_push($op,$value);
}

}
```

instead of

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($array, 'parentGroupID'), 'TesT',true);
```

gave me right results.